# Custom control with text box and text block

Tags: xaml, uwp, custom-controls, uwp-xaml

I would like to build a validation text box, which would be a normal UWP `TextBox` wrapped within a `StackPanel`, which also contains a `TextBlock`. The intent is that a validation message can be shown beneath the text box when there is a validation error.

I know I can do this by creating a custom control, but this would require me to implement all the properties I need and create a bunch of dependency properties, etc.

I'm hoping there is an easier way, where I can just completely derive the text box, but override the display template for it and include a label beneath it.

Comment: Are you familiar with TemplatedControl ?

Comment: Please check [TextBoxRegex XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxregex) Property that comes from community tool kit.

Answer (score -1):

You can get most of the way there in XAML using the built-in IDataErrorInfo-based validation machinery and defining a control template for the TextBox's Validation.ErrorTemplate. There's a pretty good article at [this link:](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/06/wpf-textbox-validation-idataerrorinfo.html#.XLFxR9pFyUk)

The XAML from the article at the link above follows, also check out this discussion on WPF's built-in validation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,40,2" />
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                    <Border Background="OrangeRed" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                            Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="5"
                            ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, 
                                      Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" 
                               FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white" />
                    </Border>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                    </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Not sure what the down-vote is for since the answer meets the requirements of the OP and uses built-in machinery rather than having to roll your own.